# Can I add an electrical outlet from a light switch box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, bathroom

I had sconces in bathroom that also had plugs attached.  Replaced sconces now there are no electrical outlets. Is it possible to run an outlet off of the light switch to the side or below existing light switch?

Comment: Sure, but is there something more specific you'd like to know than whether it's possible or not?

Comment: Is this something I can do myself with instruction? Also would a gfi switch be recommended in this situation?

Comment: You need to open up the switch box and determine if there is a neutral (white wire) available.  You definitely need a GFCI protecting a bathroom outlet. (There could already be one in your breaker box or elsewhere)

Comment: I think he's saying that the old sconces had built-in outlets [like this](https://s3.img-b.com/image/private/c_lpad,f_auto,h_320,t_base,w_320/v3/product/nuvolighting/nuvo-lighting-sf77-121b-8649713.jpg) that he was using.  Now the lights are gone, and there are no outlets in the new lights.  So it should be _possible_...

Comment: It would probably be easier to feed the new receptacles from the light boxes since you know there is a neutral at that location.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved?

Answer (score 2):

If you have something like [this switch](https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/197d809c-c6db-4db9-9786-2a278461ef3d/svn/white-eaton-switches-csb115stw-sp-64_1000.jpg)

you should be able to replace it with something like [this](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81u0Ut4GzPL._SL1500_.jpg)

This will also depend on what wires are in the box that the existing switch is in.

Comment: If there is no neutral in the switch box then you can't do that. Most older homes will not have the neutral at the switch location.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a new dedicated 20-Amp circuit to your bathroom.  The loads modern day users apply to bathroom receptacles are such that anything less is not really safe.  Could be easier that you think.  GFI protection is a given.